# Knockout checkValue not working

Tags: knockout.js

In the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) there is an example of the `checkedValue` binding which can be used to grab the `$data` object instead of the value of a checkbox. One version of the view model works while another similar version does not. Is this a bug?

Both cases use the following HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.chosenItems" />
    <span data-bind="text: itemName"></span><br>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The working view model looks like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([ { itemName: 'Choice 1' }, { itemName: 'Choice 2' }]),
    chosenItems: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v2HAg/

The similar broken view model looks like this:

```
function viewModel() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([ { itemName: 'Choice 1' }, { itemName: 'Choice 2']);
    this.chosenItems = ko.observableArray();
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dPBeA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dPBeA/ you have included both Knockout 3.x and Knockout 2.x

When I removed the reference to Knockout 2.x the code worked for me. Make sure you are only including Knockout 3.x

Once you do that your code works fine.

```
function viewModel() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([ { itemName: 'Choice 1' }, { itemName: 'Choice 2']);
    this.chosenItems = ko.observableArray();
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you like to namespace your models and related functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/dPBeA/1/

```
(function (testing, $, undefined) {
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray([{
            itemName: 'Choice 1'
        }, {
            itemName: 'Choice 2'
        }]);
        self.chosenItems = ko.observableArray();
    }

    testing.ViewModel = viewModel;
}(window.testing = window.testing || {}, jQuery));

ko.applyBindings(new testing.ViewModel());
```